# Escriba una función en C++ que reciba una lista de números e indique si un número se encuentra en el listado o no

Tags: c++

función en C++ que reciba una lista de números e indique si un número se encuentra en
el listado o no. Si se encuentra, debe retornar la posición en la que se encuentra, si n o se encuentra,
debe retornar -1.

nunca supe como se hace eso, alguien podria ayudarme?

Comment: Recorre el arreglo con un ciclo y si el número que buscas coincide retorna la posición. Si termina el ciclo significa que no halló el número entonces retorna -1

Comment: Hola bienvenido a stack overflow en español te invito a terminar [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y puedas obtener tu primer medalla. También te invito a que pases a la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar tus oportunidades de obtener una respuesta a tus preguntas. Si tienes mas dudas puedes ir a la página de  [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) donde encontrarás mas información de diversos temas.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Con una función que reciba como parámetros un arreglo de de numero y el numero a buscar.
No entiendo mucho de `C++` pero creo quedaría como lo siguiente:

```
int buscaNumero(arregloNumeros,numero){
    int encontrado = -1;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(arregloNumeros), i++){
        if(arregloNumeros[i] == numero){
            encontrado = i;
        }
    }
    return encontrado;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, no convirtamos este sitio en un hacedor de ejercicios.